# How to receive dropEvent when not a top level widget?

Tags: qt, pyqt5, pyside2

*Edit: this issue seems to be specific to Qt version 5.12.0. See the answers for more details and for a workaround*

I'm trying to implement a drop zone for loading files into my application. 
It works when I just show the widget as a top level widget, but it stops working as soon as I include it into another parent widget.

The problem is, altough I'm receiving `dragEnterEvent` and accepting it, I never see the `dropEvent`.

This is my widget:

```
class FileDropZone(qt.QLabel):
    """Target area for a drag and drop operation"""
    height = 33

    def __init__(self, text="Add file", parent=None):
        super().__init__(text, parent)
        stylesheet = """
            QLabel {
                border: 2px dotted #B4BDBA;
                qproperty-alignment: AlignCenter;
            }
            """
        self.setStyleSheet(stylesheet)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setFixedHeight(self.height)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        print("in drag enter event")
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            print("hasUrls()")
            event.acceptProposedAction()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        print("in drop event")
        urls = event.mimeData().urls()
        for url in urls:
            print(url.isLocalFile(), url.toLocalFile())
```

This is how I manage to make it work:

```
app = qt.QApplication([])
a = FileDropZone()
a.show()
app.exec_()
```

And this is the example where it does not work (`dragEnter` works, both prints are properly printed, but `dropEvent` does not print anything):

```
app = qt.QApplication([])
a0 = qt.QWidget()
l = qt.QHBoxLayout(a0)
a1 = FileDropZone("drop here", a0)
l.addWidget(a1)
a0.show()
app.exec_()
```

Any clues about what is broken? Does the parent need to forward the event, and if so, how should I implement it?

Comment: Great [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is a bug which was introduced in Qt 5.12.0 and will be fixed in Qt 5.12.1, see [this discussion](https://forum.qt.io/topic/97649/bug-in-qt-5-12-drag-n-drop) and this [bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-72844).

In the meantime:

> The problem can be worked around by reimplementing dragMoveEvent() and accepting the event there too.

i.e. add e.g. the following method to the `FileDropZone` class:

```py
def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
    print("in drag move event")
    if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
        print("hasUrls()")
        event.acceptProposedAction()
```

Comment: Thanks ! The workaround fixes it. I will edit my question to specify my version of Qt to readers.